# Make a search functionality without database involvement using only array

Tags: php, arrays, string

Make a search functionality without database involvement using only array e.g. if your array contain ('a','ab','abc','bca','bcd') then by putting 'a' into search field yield the results like 'a','ab','abc','bca'. also make a checkbox on search page which yield an exact value e.g. if u search 'a' then it should return only 'a'. also handle if search doesn't yield any result.

Comment: That sounds like a cool project.  So what problems hare you having?

Comment: This question will surely be closed unless you give some evidence that you've tried something. That's just how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 2):

While this sounds like a school assignment (tsk tsk), it's not that hard. You can use preg_match, or stripos if the box is checked, or a straight equals, strcmp, or strcasecmp for an unchecked box. You'd cycle through the array with a foreach, load the results into an array, and echo it back out. I'll leave the coding up to you, since it really does sound like a class assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = array('a','ab','abc','bca','bcd');
$search = 'a';
$results = array_filter(
    $myArray
    function ($value) use ($search) {
        return (strpos($value, $search) !== FALSE)
    }
);
```

Comment: or just `$results = preg_grep('/a/', $myArray)`?

Comment: Yeah, there's plenty of solutions